# How to show text over the camera Cordova/Phonegap?

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I am using the apache cordova camera plugin. Is it possible to show text over the camera? If not how could I done it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be done in two different ways.
1. Create your own plugin and draw layout over camera.
2. You can follow this [cordova custom camera plugin](https://github.com/Shakir-Khan/cordova-plugin-custom-camera) plugin. I have edited in existing plugin now you can pass one more argument 'caption' in options to show text over camera.

Comment: Thank you so much @shakir It helped a lot

Answer (score 0):

Tried this a lot you can't do it with the existing plug in yourself. Try raising a ticket in their github repo. Other than you will have to develop your own plugin or try out the camera-preview and canvas2image plugins.